# Cannot upload featured image to a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, post-thumbnails, media-library, thumbnails

For some reason I am not able to upload images OR set the Featured Image on a custom post type in my custom wordpress theme.

I have added theme support of post-thumbnails to my functions.php file and my custom post type supports it.  The link to add the featured image works and it allows me to start uploading the file.  But before the file can complete it gives me the error message "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later".  If I visit the media library directly, the file is there, but it shows an error in the custom post page.

Also, when I open the media library from the custom post page it shows as empty.

Anyone out there have any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: Check the permissions on your `uploads` folder.  Are you able to upload media in general?  Can you attach featured images to your posts (ie, the WordPress post type)?

Comment: I have checked that already.  If I go to Media > Add New Media I can upload files just fine.

Comment: Deactivate all plugins.  Does the problematic behaviour remain?  If not, reactivate your plugins one by one and try again after each one.

Comment: I do not have any plugins activated. Also this is a 100% custom theme that I have created.  Any other ideas?

Comment: check your browser's error console for javascript errors. are you enqueueing any javascript files in your theme?

Comment: Some quick Googling led me to a handful of WP Forum posts, two of which seem to indicate it might be a JavaScript issue: http://rockdio.org/ayudatech/solution-to-3-5-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload-please-try-again-later/ and http://mikekelly.myblog.arts.ac.uk/2013/04/25/tracking-down-a-wordpress-bug/ .  Hopefully these might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  I was using a function to set the thumbnail sizes incorrectly.  After I changed that function to the correct format it suddenly started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to `define( 'WP_DEBUG', FALSE );` in wp-config.php. For some reason it doesn't allow you to add featured images from a custom post type with Debugging on.

Comment: If that is true, then something else must be wrong with your code.

Comment: I tried 3 themes 3 custom types using 3 tutorials all did the same...when I turned debug off all 3 worked. Really odd.